# iOS swift reload table view cell from a detailed views

Tags: ios, swift

I want to reload a `UITableViewCell` that I edited in a detailed view. I do not want to reload the whole `UITableView`.

I already passed the `NSIndexPath` to my detailed view. How can I access the `UITableView`s `reloadRowsAtIndexPath`s from my detailed view? Preferably in `viewWillDisappear`.

Comment: You should let the table view controller update its own view. Update the model from your detail controller, and have the table view controller call reloadRowsAtIndexPaths from its viewWillAppear method.

Comment: Will the cell still be selected?

Comment: I don't think so, so you'll need to keep track of the indexPath that you passed to the detail controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With help of rdelmar I have found the answer for my problem.

Here is what I added in my TableViewController

```
 var oldIndexPath: NSIndexPath? = nil

  override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

        if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow(){
            oldIndexPath = indexPath
        }
  }

  override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {

        if let indexPath = oldIndexPath as NSIndexPath! {
            self.tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .None)
        }

   }
```